# Why does jQuery datapicker not constrain input when setting a date format?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, date-format

I have an input field that is being set as a date picker. When I initialize the dateFormat option it stops constraining the input and I can enter all sorts of rubbish dates in the text box. Why does this happen? I'd like to have constrained input still work when setting a custom date format.

```
myTextInput.datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" });
```

If I don't set the dateFormat option then the input is constrained as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be the custom date format itself that is breaking it. It appears that when your dateFormat includes a string representation that it isn't restricting.

```
$('#mydate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

This seems to work correctly.

So basically the codes M, MM, D and DD break it.

Comment: Ah ok, I get what you mean. So because the format I'm using allows dates like 12-JUL-2010, it will basically disable the constraints and allow any text. I thought it would've been smarter and only allowed the characters in JAN, FEB, MAR, etc. Any idea how to easily restrict the text entered in with jQuery?

Comment: The documentation makes it sound like it should be smarter as well. You could make your own constraint on the field to only allow numbers and alpha characters. A solution for that is here (just ignore the preview stuff) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397535/block-characters-from-input-text-field-mirror-input-into-span-or-div

Comment: i have a format of dd/mm/yy and it doesn't work, no string represantation xD