# How can I restrict the text entered into an input text element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, maskedtextbox

I have an input text element being used as a jQuery UI datepicker with a custom date format. The date format allows months to be entered in as JAN, FEB, etc and so the constrained input allows all characters to go through. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252295).

How can I restrict the text entered to match my date format "dd-M-yy"?

Is there a way to use jQuery to make the input text element behave like a masked edit text box?

Comment: Is it **dd-M-yy** or **dd-MM-yy**?

Comment: dd-M-yy e.g. 15-JUL-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [the jQuery MaskedInput plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), assuming your input is fixed-width.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit dirty, but maybe you can use http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event to create your own filter?

The plugin isn't dirty mind you, it looks great, but it might be the wrong hammer for this nail.

Comment: While Bears will eat you's answer had the closer matching tool, this answer was also very useful and I'm actually using both to implement the masking and validation that I need.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a jquery date picker 
you have built in support for this allready inside the plugin

you can specify the "constrainInput" option inside the datepicker
its a boolean just set it to true. and avcorse sepcify your date format.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-constrainInput

Comment: That doesn't work for my scenario. See the link in my question above.